# What type of encoding this is?

Tags: php

Can you please tell me what type of php encoding this is:

```
<?php $ONbp = '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';$cD = '$LVt = base64_decode($ONbp); eval($LVt);';eval($cD);?>
```

and can we decode this ? If yes how can I ?

Comment: `base64_decode($ONbp);` *cough*

Comment: Gee, I wonder what `base64_decode` means.

Comment: These are often injected into hacked websites - WordPress is a popular recipient of this kind of hack. Can you say how you came by this code? If you run the base64 decoding, you'll see some of the workings. Just don't run it with `eval`, unless you are in a virtual machine you will throw away.

Comment: Its `base64_encode()`ed like 6-7 times. boils down to this. `$cvzz .= ''; $cvzz .= ''; $cvzz .= ''; $cvzz .= ''; $cvzz .= ''; $cvzz .= ''; $cvzz .= ''; $cvzz .= ''; $cvzz .= ''; $cvzz .= ''; $cvzz .= getextrasetting('MTOTH'); $cvzz .= ''; $cvzz .= ''; echo $cvzz; unset($cvzz); `

Comment: (See also [the many duplicates of this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=base64+eval+php)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of encoding is called Base64 - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

You can decode it using `base64_decode()` function in PHP (as you can see it attached snippet) or online there - https://www.base64decode.org/

Comment: Hi, I tried base64 already and that gives me another set of coding http://pastebin.com/GGkAanJj

Comment: @IndianGirl Yeah I also tired that. This is kind of recursive base64. You need to decode it as many times as you will get plain text

Comment: @IndianGirl I am really glad I could help. If my answer was helpful please mark it as accepted please :-)